# NSMutableURLRequest remove "+" sign from request

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS app which required to send phone number on server.
When I pass number without "+" it is work fine, but when I pass number with "+" sign (+123456, +234567) then it send number like (" 123456"," 234567").

It replace "+" by " " (space).
I convert NSDictionary into JsonData .

```
NSError *err;
    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mdict options:0 error:&err];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *strjson=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GetData=%@",str];

    NSLog(@"strjson=%@",strjson);
```

My code to build NSMutableRequest object.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    __weak NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soadMessage length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[soadMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [_connection start];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters() and pass your desired character set to string URL.

Comment: Actually, I need to send "+" on server. NOT WANT to remove "+" sign

Comment: I am getting "+" into NSLog(@"strjson=%@",strjson);.
But on server it shows without "+" sign. That is the issue.

Comment: Can you show us a part of the json with the number?

Comment: GetData={"retail_number":"+911234567890","name":"simulator"}

Comment: You're not showing how you build your "urlString", but you probably go the escaping wrong: http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding

Comment: Unrelated, but if you use `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]` method, you should _not_ call `start`, as the request has already been started for you. You're starting it twice. You only use `start` method if you call `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:]` with `FALSE` for that last parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape your string with the `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`

```
+ (NSString *)escapeValueForURLParameter:(NSString *)valueToEscape {

    if (![valueToEscape isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    valueToEscape = [(id)valueToEscape stringValue];
}

return (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) valueToEscape,
                                                                              NULL, (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the `%`, `#`, `[`, and `]` characters are not needed here, as `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` will percent escape them even if you don't include them in the `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped`. It doesn't hurt to include them, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the value of `mdict` to take out the `+` character. Or you could also trim it from the JSON at the end. Either way you will get the desired result.

Something like this:

```
mdict["Phone"].value = [mdict["Phone"].value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                                     withString:@""];
```

This is pseudocode but you get the idea. After doing this you can do the serialization and it should be fine.